# Node.js - Javascript - How to pass variables to a callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am working with Node.js streams and end up with something like this in several places:

```
var myVariable = 'XXX';
...
.on('end', function() {
    // do something with myVariable
});
```

The behaviour of the function is the same but depends on a variable so I would like to refactor it to:

```
var myVariable = 'XXX';
...
.on('end', myFunction);


function myFunction(param){
    // do something with param
}
```

How can I pass the value of `myVariable` in the call `.on('end', myFunction);`?

Comment: Where do you normally get `param` from?

Comment: It is not clear what you actually want. Do you want to pass the variable as a parameter to the function, apart from the value given by the `end` event?

Comment: I just updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would make a factory that returns customized functions to be used as the callback.

```
function myFactory(param) {
    return function(e) {
        console.log( 'param value:', param );
        // do something
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
.on('end', myFactory(1));

.on('end', myFactory(2));
```

If the "end" event passes some parameters to the callback other than or in addition to the event object, add them to the returned function's parameter list (`return function(e, foo, bar) { ...`)

Comment: I was thinking of answering something like this. +1

Comment: Thanks Juhana, I should've figured out myself!

Comment: @Juhana Maybe it would be better if the `factory` will separate functions, which at the input will accept parameters and a reference to a callback function?

Answer (score 1):

your callback function should be defined like this way:

```
function myCallback(myParam) {
  // do some stuff
  return myReturn;
}
```

when you declare your listener, the "on" method, should take the name of the event, and the reference of your method callback:

```
.on('eventName', myCallback);
```

and when you emit the event, there is where you pass params:

```
emit('eventName', myParam);
```

then in your callback, you can retrieve params